# Typeorm, MongoDB and where operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nestjs, typeorm

[TypeORM with MongoDB type]. Hello I have db with users where each user have a email prop, now I want to find all users on which email starts with "test" for example and return value should be User[{email: 'test1'}, {email: 'test2'}, ...] but I'm not able to pull these entities here how i do my query:

```
 const users = await this.usersRepository.find({
    where: `"email" LIKE 'test%'`,
 });
```

But this code returns the whole collection of users. I also try it with:

I also try it with:

```
    const users = await this.usersRepository.find({
        where: {
            email: Like('test')
        }
    });
```

This one return empty array []

Even if I try with exact match for example Like('test21@abv.bg'), still returns empty array

How I can achieve to get all users on which email starts with 'test' thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MongoDB use regex

```
const users = await this.usersRepository.find({
    where: {
        email: new RegExp(`^${userEmail}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: returns empty array

Comment: @AndonMitev it seems strange. Try running raw SQL 
SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE "email" LIKE 'test%'
to double check that there is no problems with your data

Comment: I'd try putting your conditions directly as find method argument e.g 
.find({
        email: Like('test%')
});
but I suppose it won't make any difference.
Reference: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md#advanced-options

Comment: Yes there is no difference I'm using MongoDB with TypeORM

Comment: @AndonMitev it changed everything.
You need to use regex in your case 
{ email: /^test/ }

Comment: you are top man! and now if u have idea how to make test dynamic in this regex would be awesome!

Comment: @AndonMitev sure. You can use RegExp instance for this. 

Example: { email: new RegExp(\`^${userEmail}\`) }

Comment: @AndonMitev mind if I replace the answer with the correct one?

Comment: Thanks. Using TypeORM's ILike did not work. 
For Typescript, I declare a where like this so that we can assign a RegExp into field condition : `const where: FindConditions<YourEntity> | ObjectLiteral = {};`

Comment: `Type 'RegExp' is not assignable to type 'string | FindOperator<string>'.ts(2322)`